# Integer not receiving Null value from Mysql - Hibernate/JPA . Java Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is Hibernate JPA, Spring related question.

I am storing int`s in mysql. Some of them have int values some of them have null`s.

When i persist into db everything works fine, but when i bind values back to object Integer does not receive null?! and application crashes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="oglas")
public class OglasJPA {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="spratnost_objekta_ID")
private SpratnostObjektaJPA spratnostObjekta;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="spratnost_objekta")
public class SpratnostObjektaJPA {

@Id
@Column(name="idspratnost_objekta")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
private Integer id;

@Column(name="spratnost_objekta")
private Integer spratnost;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="spratnostObjekta")
private List<OglasJPA> listaOglasaZaSpratnostObjekta;


public List<Oglas> getAllOglas(){
List<OglasJPA> listaOglasaJPA = getOglasRepository().getAllOglas();
for(OglasJPA oglasJPA : listaOglasaJPA){
System.out.println(oglasJPA.getSpratnostObjekta().getId());
}
```

code is shortened for easier reviewing.

Application works as long as in(11) from db has int value. When for loop hits null program breaks with nested exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Any chance of a stack trace?

Comment: My guess is oglasJPA.getSpratnostObjekta() is null

Comment: @JamesB

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.smb.nekretnine.service.OglasService.getAllOglas(OglasService.java:56)
 com.smb.nekretnine.service.OglasService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d37cdd04.invoke(<generated>)
 net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)

Comment: line 56 is    System.out.println(oglasJPA.getSpratnostObjekta().getId());

these are results before application crash 

4
3
7
8
these are the mysql values
4
3
7
8
null
null
5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. 
Problem is EntityManager tries to retrieve Entity with id null. It has slipped my mind that value in table represents an object, as it is foreign key to another table. try-catch solves the problem! Still cant believe i didnt realize this sooner. Well i guess strange things happen after 7 days/12hours a day coding!